# Mat form field outline with border radius problem rendering

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to make my input field with a rounded outline. This field is in a radio button.

My HTML is:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button value="1">
        <form class="example-form">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Input" matInput [formControl]="myControl">
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
    </mat-radio-button>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="2">All</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

CSS:

```
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
}
```

When I change the border radius to achieve the desired outline, this is the result:
How can I remove the line on the left?

[image: Render Problem]

Comment: you have to debug in the console. There is an element in an element in an element in an element... you have to find out which one renders the left border...

Comment: @Random yes, I tried that. I cannot seem to focus on the problem line...

Comment: Can you do a plunkr (or other) then to help you find this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Here is the solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-tachfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

All you had to do was this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

a bit late to the party but I think I might have a better solution :)

When you check out Material CSS you can see they had the end part of the outline the only one with `flex-grow:1` so it takes the most space out of the 3 parts.

My first try was to give the start part the same prop, and then I got the input looking like it was composed of 2 almost-whole circles [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpDzQ.png) .

Then I looked at how Material originaly defined their outline border-radius and discovered they differ between the parts - at the start they used 0 for the top and bottom right, and 5px for the top and bottom left, while at the end part it was the opposite.

So I changed the definitions accordingly and it works perfectly now.

- I've also added a specific class in the html so that this `::ng-deep` will not have an effect on all mat-form-field uses in the app.

html:

```
<div style="padding: 20%">

  <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button value="1">
      <form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-form-round">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Input" matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
    </mat-radio-button>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="2">All</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

scss:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-round {
  .mat-form-field-outline {
    &-end {
      border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0 !important;
    }

    &-start {
      border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px !important;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the full stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-zw4fbx?file=src/app/app.component.scss